# How to recreate iA Writer-style typewriter scrolling in Emacs?

Tags: scrolling

The popular Mac editor iA Writer (https://ia.net/writer/mac/) has many nifty features that I rather like. So far, I've been able to recreate the look and feel for the most part -- except for the typewriter-style scrolling that keeps the current line centered in the window. Any ideas on how to implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`centered-cursor-mode` Makes the cursor stay vertically in a defined position (usually centered). The vertical position can be altered, see key definition below. http://melpa.org/#/centered-cursor-mode

```
(use-package centered-cursor-mode)
```

and then add `(centered-cursor-mode)` to your `org` hook.

Comment: This mode is incompatible with automatic line wrapping.